# Append unique values MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables, the source called **"QA"** and the destination table called **"Combine"**. I will like to append only unique records base on the [Call_ID] criteria. I need help with the **where clause**, the insert query is:

```
INSERT INTO combine ( source, date_update, [Year], [Month], [Day], quarter, week, QAcount, sup, agent_name, QA_A, date_c, login_name, QA_CALL_ID )
SELECT "QA" AS source, Date() AS CURDATE, Year([date_c]) AS Y, Month([date_c]) AS M, Day([date_c]) AS D, DatePart('q',[date_c]) AS Q, Weekday([date_c],1) AS W, "1" AS [count], Roster.Supervisor, Roster.agent_name, QA.QA_A, QA.date_c, QA.login_name, QA.[Call ID]
FROM QA LEFT JOIN Roster ON QA.login_name = Roster.tCAM;
```

Insert only where **[QA].[Call ID]** is different from **[combine].[QA_CALL_ID]** AND Is not null. Please help me with this sentence.

[image]

Comment: We could really use some more information. Sample data, and your desired results. Dumping the query into a question can *sometimes* help, but usually we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE [QA].[Call ID] <> [combine].[QA_CALL_ID] AND [combine].[QA_CALL_ID] NOT IS NULL
```

maybe missing any the parenthesis that Access likes to use a ton of..